# grid()/grid_remove() functions don't do i would expect

Tags: python, tkinter, grid, hide

So I am making a "game", where there is a grid with random number from 1 to 9 in each cell. And when you move the cursor on a cell, and press the number on your keyboard which is written in the cell, it should disappear, and another cell should reappear. I am trying to use `grid_remove()` for hide the object, and `grid()` to show it, but it doesn't work as I would like to it. Firstly I make a 3x3 grid, and i remove some of its cells, but the shown cells can be shifted to the place of a hidden one and I would avoid of this. In this code, I write the index in the each cell (instead of a random number 1-9). I highlight a part of the code in the beginning, where I remove the cells at the program starting, then i past the whole code.

Choosing which indexes will be removed (I think it should be ok):

```
exist=[]
t=0
for k in range(0,int((2*size*size)/3)):
    while t in exist:
        t=randint(0,size*size-1)
    print(t)
    exist.append(t)
```

Removing some of the cells, right after making them:

```
button[index].grid(row=i, column=j)
if index in exist:
    button[index].grid_remove()
```

And my whole code finally:

```
from random import randint
import tkinter
from tkinter import Button
from tkinter import font
top = tkinter.Tk()
top.title("Game")
top.geometry("500x500")

class table:                            
    def __init__(self,size):            
        self.size=size
        index=0
        def onClick(index):
            if button[index].cget("bg")=="Red":
                button[index].config(bg="Blue")
            else:
                button[index].config(bg="Red")
        def key(event):
            if event.widget.cget("text")==event.char:
                event.widget.config(text=str(randint(1,9)))
                event.widget.show=False
                f=randint(0,size*size-1)
                if not button[f].winfo_exists():
                    button[f].grid()  #row=int(f/size), column=f%size
        def enter(event):
            event.widget.focus_set()
        def leave(event):
            event.widget.config(bg="Red")
        button=[]
        exist=[]
        t=0
        for k in range(0,int((2*size*size)/3)):
            while t in exist:
                t=randint(0,size*size-1)
            print(t)
            exist.append(t)
        for i in range(0, size):        
            for j in range (0,size):
                button.append(Button(top,command=lambda index=index: onClick(index),height=5,width=10,bg="Red",font=5,text=str(index)))
                button[index].bind("<Key>",key)
                button[index].bind("<Enter>",enter)
                button[index].bind("<Leave>",leave)
                button[index].grid(row=i, column=j)
                if index in exist:
                    button[index].grid_remove()
                index=index+1    
racs=table(3)
top.mainloop()
```

Comment: What _do_ you expect?

Comment: It sounds like you would be better off modifying the widgets in the grid rather than removing them and replacing them.

Comment: It looks like it's behaving correctly to me. It's removing those items that are in `exist`. When I ran it, `exist` contains 0, 2, 3, 1, 4, and 6, and the buttons I see are 5, 7, and 8.

Comment: functions inside `__init__` - what a mess.

Comment: empty rows/columns has no size so it looks like other rows/columns have been shifted. You may have to set default size for rows and columns.

Comment: Oh yes furas, that is exactly my problem, now i looked for some solution, to set a default column/row size, but i didn't find anything useful. :(
"minsize" option has no effect if the row/column is completely empty. So can you give any advice please? :)